# i want to scroll a voew to right and click on 3 dots, sometimes automatically it detects the button, sometimes not

Tags: automation, scroll, cypress

I have to scroll right in cypress for a specific view part. Sometimes it automatically detect, but sometimes after scroll only it detect the button. Scrollbar has no unique ID. What is the solution for this scenario?

I tried cy.scroll(500,0) but this dont work

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element then use [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollintoview#docusaurus_skipToContent_fallback) chained to the returned element.

```
cy.get('#uniqueId')
  .scrollIntoView()
  // now it will be in current viewport
```

Comment: What is this uiqueid here, i have no unique id

Comment: Whatever your selector is for getting the element you are looking for.

Comment: i dont have a selctor for scroll